# how to display database return error message in java adf

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle-adf

1.1.9.0 I have method calling procedure,i what to display those msg which are been return in my procedure how can I do that

my method is

```
public void validUsr(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uIComponent, Object object){

           String inputString =object.toString().toUpperCase();

       // executeQueryADF("cal.SignId(?)",new Object[] {inputString});

        callPerformSdmsLogon("cal.SignId(?)",new Object[] {inputString});

    }
```

this is how my procedure define

`procedure SignId(p_signid varchar2,PROC_ERR_MSG OUT varchar2)` I

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure weather I understood you correctly but if you want to display a message you need something like this:

```
public void showMessage(String messageText) {
        FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(messageText);
        fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, fm);
}
```

Here a source https://mjabr.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/how-to-show-afmessage-programatically/

Comment: i what to display that massage am getting from procedure

Comment: So your question is how to get a message from procedure but in Java?

Comment: public void validUsr(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uIComponent, Object object){
           String inputString =object.toString().toUpperCase();
           
       // executeQueryADF("calmain.SignId(?)",new Object[] {inputString});
           
           String msg = null;
        
        callPerformSdmsLogon("calmain.SignId(?,?)",new Object[] {inputString,msg});
        
        if(msg != null){
            //System.out.println(msg);
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,msg,null));
        }
            
    }

Comment: how to get the procedure return msg in java

Answer (score 0):

> public void validUsr(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uIComponent, Object object){ String inputString =object.toString().toUpperCase(); // executeQueryADF("calmain.SignId(?)",new Object[] {inputString}); String msg = null; callPerformSdmsLogon("calmain.SignId(?,?)",new Object[] {inputString,msg}); if(msg != null){ //System.out.println(msg); throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,msg,null)); } }

If you only want to show  your message you don't have to throw an exception but you can do something like this:

```
public void validUsr(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uIComponent, Object object){ 
 String inputString =object.toString().toUpperCase(); 
 String msg = null; 
 callPerformSdmsLogon("calmain.SignId(?,?)",new Object[] {inputString,msg}); 
 if(msg != null){ 
    showMessage(msg); 
 } 
}

public void showMessage(String messageText) {
    FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(messageText);
    fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addMessage(null, fm);
}
```

Still I am not sure what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: am not able to implement this in my appmodule am geting error

Comment: public void signOnId(String signid){
            ViewObject svo = this.findViewObject("CalMain1");
           // Row row = svo.first();
            Row row = null;
            String msg = null;           
            String val = (String)row.getAttribute("SignId");
            callPerformSdmsLogon("calmain.SignId(?,?)",new Object[] {val,msg});            
            if (msg != null) {
                System.out.println(msg);               
                
            }
            
        }

Comment: can you follow this https://community.oracle.com/thread/3817127?sr=inbox&ru=703955

Comment: Perhaps you should start a new thread with this error? It looks like a different issue